# Can I fit v brakes on 2003 Marzocchi MX Pro Suspension Forks

Tags: fork

I've got some very similar forks to this

[image]

and I want to know if I can use v brakes with them. It looks like there is a thread to screw in some bosses, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need adaptors such as [these](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XMarzocchi+V-Brake+Stud+Boss+%2F+Sleeve+Kit.TRS0&_nkw=Marzocchi+V-Brake+Stud+Boss+%2F+Sleeve+Kit&_sacat=0).

Edit: To the best of my knowledge, all Marzocchi v brake adaptors are the same, but you might want to ask the eBay vendor just to be on the safe side :)